# Overload Matlab's parse function in class inputParser

Tags: matlab, class, object, overloading

I want to overload the `parse` function in the class `inputParser`:

```
classdef inputParser2 < inputParser
  methods
    function parse(obj, varargin)
      parse@inputParser(obj, varargin{:});
    end
  end
end
```

When I now execute

```
p2 = inputParser2;
addRequired(p2, 'A');
addRequired(p2, 'B');
addRequired(p2, 'C');
parse(p2, 1, 2, 3);
```

I get the error message

```
Error using inputParser2/parse
Too many input arguments.
```

Why is that? I'm using here `varargin`, so a varaiable number of input arguments can be delivered.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. What version of MATLAB?

Comment: Be sure to run `clear classes` to clear out previous incorrect class definitions.

Comment: Indeed this was the problem, calling `clear classes` resolved it. Thanks very much!